# Sublime - PyCodeStyle - Line Length Property

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, pycodestyle

I'm editing SublimeLinter prefences trying to set line lenth in 100, but I can't get it to work

I tried with

```
{
"linters": {
"pycodestyle": {
  "ignore": "E501"
}
}
}
```

And

```
{
"linters": {
"pycodestyle": {
  "max-line-length": 100
}
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I cant get it to work" is unclear. Whats the issue? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the line length settings are not really changing, and I keep getting <79 characters per line as an error (default value) despite the configuration.

For some reason it seems that the configuration I'm modifying doesn't work.